# Stack overflow 6 vba

Tags: vba, stack, overflow

I used code gleaned from various sites to read a flat file which has separator for each record. The code works great except when the number of records in the file crosses more than 505  it gives a run time error 6 error. Can you help on what to do about this? I do not have a VBA background, but just used the questions from other to put together this code for an application

```
Sub Posting()

Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim ColNdx As Integer
Dim TempVal As Variant
Dim WholeLine As String
Dim Pos As Integer
Dim NextPos As Integer
Dim SaveColNdx As Integer
Dim FName As String

Range("A2").Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.ClearContents
   Range("A1").Select


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'On Error GoTo EndMacro:

Sep = "@"

FName = Application.GetOpenFilename


If sFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub

Cells(1, 8).Value = Mid(FName, Len(FName) - 8, 4)

SaveColNdx = ActiveCell.Column
RowNdx = ActiveCell.Row

Open FName For Input Access Read As #1

While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, WholeLine
     If Right(WholeLine, 1) <> Sep Then
         WholeLine = WholeLine & Sep
    End If
    ColNdx = SaveColNdx
    Pos = 1
    NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
     While NextPos >= 1
        TempVal = Mid(WholeLine, Pos, NextPos - Pos)
        Cells(ColNdx, RowNdx).Value = TempVal
        Pos = NextPos + 1
        ColNdx = ColNdx + 1
        NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
    Wend
RowNdx = RowNdx + 1
Wend
```

The run time error 6 overflow  is being shown on `NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)`

Comment: Pos is larger than the length of WholeLine I guess. Use some Debug.Print statements to verify or set a break point in the debugger

Answer (score 3):

You declare `NextPos` as Integer, which allows for number up the 32768. If `InStr(` returns a value higher than this, an `Overflow` error is caused.

Simply change the data type to `Long`and your problem will be fixed!

I also think that you're mixing up the parameters in  `Cells(ColNdx, RowNdx)` - be aware, that `Cells` expects the row as the first parameter and the column as the second!

BTW:
Instead of your manual splitting of the text, you could also use the built-in `Split` function:

```
Dim varSplitted as Variant

...
While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, WholeLine
    varSplitted = Split(WholeLine, Sep)
    Range(RowNdx,SaveColNdx).Resize(, UBound(varSplitted, 1)+1) = varSplitted
    RowNdx = RowNdx + 1
Wend
```